# How to trigger Material2 <mat-error> to be displayed on input-change

Tags: angular-material2, angular5

Given the example at https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Form field with error messages */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-error-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-error-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-error-example.css']
})
export class FormFieldErrorExample {
  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
        this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
            '';
  }
}
```

The error seems to be triggered on-blur. Only after leaving the input does the error appears. It is the same in my application. In this current mode, error exist but the  is not displayed until the input loses focus.

How can I trigger the error to be displayed when the input change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the **[docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown)** you need to use an `errorStateMatcher`.

For you that would look like this:

```ts
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
  }
}
```

and in your component do:

```ts
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

Then just add in your input field

```ts
[errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyjwbn?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html)

Comment: Could you please also explain what is the purpose of `[formControl]="email"` in the StackBlitz? There is no `formControl` property exposed by the component and also `FormControl` doesn't seem to be a directive. So I'm confused here.

Comment: this did not solve the problem. the required error still gets triggered on blur

Answer (score 2):

and in your component class:

```
matcher = {
  isErrorState: () => {
    return this.statusField; // return Boolean status value
  }
};
```

Then just add in your matInput field

```
[errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
```

Comment: This answer also works for simple inputs using ngModel

Comment: What is statusField? It doesn't exists