# Angular form validation working only after focus change

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a angular form on which I want to do some validation. Now, when the textarea is loaded for the first time and I type something violating the validation, it does not show me error.

When I change focus to some other element, then the error is shown.

But, after that whenever there is a violation, the error is shown immediately whithout focus change required.

```
<form [formGroup]="AddEditform" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <textarea matInput name="user" formControlName="users" id="user">
        </textarea>
        <mat-error
            *ngIf="!AddEditform.valid && AddEditform.get('users').hasError('maxlength')"
        >
            Exceeded maximum length
        </mat-error>
    </<mat-form-field>
</form>


AddEditform: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.AddEditform = this.fb.group({
    users: [
      '',
      [
        Validators.maxLength(100)
      ],
    ],
  });
}
```

Why is this behavior happening? Why on the first time itself, the validation is not happening without focus change required?

Comment: you might want to try `[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'change'}"` on your text area

Comment: @TheFabio I'm getting `Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'`

Comment: when you create your form, you can pass the config there instead `yourForm = new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'change'});` 
it might be that mat sets the defaults on its tags

Comment: @TheFabio Tried, still same problem. First time working only on error shown only on focus change

Answer (score 5):

Solution of same found in [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vuxxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Error is in your `<mat-error>`, is not firing when input value change validation is occurs.
for solution of that you have to user custom `ErrorStateMatcher` in your class.ts file and you need to tell in template that you need custom `ErrorStateMatcher`.

**component.html**

```
<form  novalidate autocomplete="off">
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
         <textarea matInput #inputValue name="user" 
              [formControl]="users" id="user" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" >
         </textarea>
       <mat-error>
         Exceeded maximum length
       </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular';
    AddEditform: FormGroup;
    users = new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(5)]);
    matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

    ngOnInit(){ }
}

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
       isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
            const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
            return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

based on [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group)

> updateOn: The event upon which the control should be updated (options: 'change' | 'blur' | submit')

it's worked for me

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.AddEditform = this.fb.group({
     users: ['', [Validators.required]],
   },{updateOn: 'blur'} )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the options too. It really helped!

Comment: What if you are making a custom component? can it be done within the formcontrol itselF?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea about this matter @chitgoks

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `updateOn` attribute to your [form group](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group):

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.AddEditform = this.fb.group({
    users: [
      '',
      [
        Validators.maxLength(100)
      ],
    ],
  },
 {updateOn: 'change'} 
);
}
```

That should trigger the validations every time the model value changes.

Comment: Tried, still same problem. First time working only on error shown only on focus change

Comment: This is what you're after (similar to the answer below) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535779/how-to-trigger-material2-mat-error-to-be-displayed-on-input-change