# Need to show the error message in mat errror based on the if condition in component

Tags: angular, angular6, mat-error

I want to show the error message in mat error based on the if condition in component.

```
export class EditMaterialComponent implements OnInit {

  public quantityRemaining:any;
  public editMaterialForm = new FormGroup({
    count: new FormControl(''),
    suppliedTo: new FormControl('')
  })
  public errormatcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditMaterialComponent>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any,private inventoryMngService:InventoryMngService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dialogData);

  }


  /** CLOSE mat dialog **/
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close(null);
  }
  updateQuantity(){

    this.dialogData.count = this.dialogData.count - this.editMaterialForm.value.count;
    this.dialogData.comment = this.editMaterialForm.value.suppliedTo;
    if(this.editMaterialForm.valid){
     this.inventoryMngService.updateICase(this.dialogData).subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res);
       this.close();
      },err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
    }

}
}
```

In the `updateQuantity()`, if `this.editMaterialForm.value.count > this.dialogData.count`  need to show the error in `<mat-error></mat-error>`.
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: You have [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535779/how-to-trigger-material2-mat-error-to-be-displayed-on-input-change) thread, it may be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom validator like this:

```
export const validateCondition = (condition: (control: AbstractControl) => boolean, errorString: string): ValidatorFn => 
  (control: AbstractControl): ValidatorErrors =>
  (condition(control) ? null : { [errorString]: { value: control.value } });
```

You can use it like this:

```
editMaterialForm = new FormGroup({
  count: new FormControl('', [validateCondition(control => control.value > this.dialogData.count, 'myCustomError')]),
  suppliedTo: new FormControl('')
})
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="FormControl.hasError('myCustomError')">message</mat-error>
```

Comment: It is not working bro ,We re not passing value for the has error in the html

Comment: @ajay Sorry I didn't understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: ,myCustomError going as undefined

Comment: @ajay One reason could be that you change `this.dialog.count` and you won't revalidate the formControl. You need to call `this.editMaterialForm.get('count').validate()` after changing `this.dialog.count`

Comment: i used the div tag itself to show the error based on the flag .anyway thanks.